# How to send contact form from a pure HTML/JS website to a external webservice in a Django Project?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, web-services, rest

I have a website with html5/javascript/css3 and I must send the contact form values to a web service in an external webservice located in a django project(with piston/rest). I have loaded the Json with the values into a Jquery/Ajax and sent to a Javascript function into the Django Project. This is the Js in the Form website:

```
var json = "{\"nome\": "+nome
    +", \"empresa\": "+empresa
    +", \"email\": "+email
    +", \"telefone\": "+telefone
    +", \"assunto\": "+assunto
    +", \"mensagem\": "+mensagem
    +"}";
try{
    ws("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wsname/", json,"POST","","", "alert(ws_returned_info)", "");
}catch(erros){
    alert(erros.message);
}
```

and the ws function in the Django Project works fine when it called from the self project, but in the catch it alerts "responseText is undefined"

```
function ws( p_url, p_json, p_type, p_auth, p_before, p_success, p_finally ){
    var resposta = true;
    preLoader.show();

    dict = { url: p_url,
             beforeSend: function(request){
                            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "*" );
                            request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
                            eval(p_before);
                         },
             cache: false,
             type: p_type,
             data: p_json,
             async: false,
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             processData: false,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(json, textStatus){
                        eval(p_success);
                      },
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        erros(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        resposta = false;
                      }
            };

    $.ajax(dict);

    preLoader.fadeOut("fast");
    eval(p_finally);

    return resposta;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a django url at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wsname/`, and you want to send JSON to it from a separate app.

What does `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/wsname/` do? My guess is that it is not sending a correct response back to your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be in development, so you can look at the console and see if the request is received by the django app, and how it is answered:

- Your Django app (in the console, so), might reply with a `401 Forbidden` response, which will indicate that you didn't disable CSRF protection for this view, which, given your use case, you must.
- Your app might reply with a `500 Internal Server Error` response, which would indicate a coding error in your view.
- Your app might reply with a `200 OK` response, which will indicate that the error is somewhere in the JS.
- There could be nothing in the console, which would indicate an issue sending the request. Check out the logs from a JS debugger to see what the error is.